# Proving the convergence of a series by proving a property of the natural log function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms

I am looking to establish the convergence of
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\log(n)}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$
I have seen a previous article ([Prove the convergence of : $\sum \ln(n)/n^{3/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747354/prove-the-convergence-of-sum-lnn-n3-2/747388)) looking into this.

The Cauchy Condensation Test is not something I would be able to use yet, as it is not taught.

I see assertions without proof that (*) for all $\alpha \gt 0$, $\log(n)\lt n^\alpha$ eventually, and using the p-test, this solves the problem. How can I prove such a result?

Another method I tried was using the integral test, but here I am assuming that the expression is decreasing as $n$ increases, and I find that the convergence is dependent on whether
$$\frac{\log(n)}{n^\frac{1}{2}}$$
converges, and now I have a similar problem to before.

I am looking in particular for a proof of (*), but any alternate methods with proof would be great too! Thank you

Comment: You can just use L'Hopital to prove $\frac{\log n}{n^\alpha}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht this is a question from a past exam in which I would not be allowed to use L'Hopital

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes sorry that's why I said 'eventually'

Comment: Missed the word “eventually” on first reading. @jaycneek